# Validating value on submit button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to setup validation in jQuery. It's not working, what should I do on submit button and jQuery code?

```js
function validate() {
  var total = $('#total').val();
  var limit = 1000;

  if (total > limit) {
    alert('numbers cannot exceed the limit');
    return false;
  } else {
    // submit
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="total"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
```

Comment: parse total to number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Devsi Odedra comment, you should parse the value to number to be able to compare instead of comparing string as well.

```js
$('#total').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) 
       && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});

function validate() {
   var total = parseFloat($('#total').val());
   var limit = 1000;

   if(total > limit) {
      alert('numbers cannot exceed the limit');
      return false;
   } else {
      // submit
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="total"></input> and submit button <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
```

**Updated**

You should validate to only allow input float number like this

```
$('#total').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why using `parseFloat()` not `parseInt()`?

Comment: I tried input 1100, but condition statement give me `true` return (running a `//submit` block)

Comment: Really? Please check again. Btw, You should validate to accept number value only. https://ibb.co/G5dJDJ5

Comment: I've just updated my answer with some improvement. Please have a look at @Yudhistira

Comment: @mamoun othman . I'm using `parseFloat()` simply because i'm not sure the value is interger only.

Comment: @Phong In snippet code is work. Evidently, I wrong define the varible :D Thank once again, and thank you for Devsi Odedra

Answer (score 0):

you should use **button** type instead of submit because submit must be use under the form tag

```js
function validate() {
  var total = $('#total').val();
  var limit = 1000;

  if (total > limit) {
    alert('numbers cannot exceed the limit');
    return false;
  } else {
    // submit
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="total"></input>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="validate()">
```